# Replace internal Wordpress links with Next.js Link Component

Tags: javascript, wordpress, graphql, next.js

I am developing **Next.js app** using **Wordpress as headless CMS + GraphQL**. Everything is clear except for internal content links in articles which I get via WP API. Such links are plain `<a></a>` and trigger browser reloading. Is there any solution to replace them with `Link Component`?

Answer (score 2):

I think you content should include in your Next.js app, then on content's parent element, you can bind a `onClick` handler to capture click on links and use `router.push` to simulate `<Link>` behaviours like:

```
<div onClick={e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.target.href) router.push(e.target.href);
}}>
  internal content with links
</div>
```